# Swipe not working for youtube video in react-slick

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I have built the `react carousel component` using **react-slick**. It includes youtube video player section. For this video player, I used tag.

Everything works well but swiping event doesn't work on video part. When I swipe on this, it **doesn't slide next but just plays the video**.